# Crayons concat gives NULL

Tags: r

I am using

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 18.3
```

and `tidyverse_1.2.1`. Using the `%+%` operator provided by the `crayons` package (loaded by `tdiyverse`) gives `NULL`. Why? Is this a bug?

E.g. reproducing the example from the manual gives:

```
> "foo" %+% "bar" %>% print
NULL
```

instead of "foobar".

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. `library(crayon); "foo" %+% "bar" %>% print` returns `"foobar"` for me (`tidyverse_1.2.1` and `R version 3.5.1`). Have you tried from a fresh R terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot2` has its own version of `%+%`, which can mask the one from `crayon`. If I make sure that I load `ggplot2`/`tidyverse` first, before loading `crayon`, I get the expected results:

```
> library(tidyverse)
-- Attaching packages ---------------------- tidyverse 1.2.1 --
v ggplot2 3.1.0     v purrr   0.2.5
v tibble  1.4.2     v dplyr   0.7.8
v tidyr   0.8.2     v stringr 1.3.1
v readr   1.2.1     v forcats 0.3.0
-- Conflicts ------------------------- tidyverse_conflicts() --
x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
> library(crayon)

Attaching package: ‘crayon’

The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:

    %+%

> "foo" %+% "bar" %>% print
[1] "foobar"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed just because both `ggplot2` and `crayon` define a `%+%` function! Then which function is used will depend on the order of the packages loaded, making your code fragile.

To make sure to avoid any conflict, you can give an alias to these operators, such as (see [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775062/r-conflict-between-two-definitions-of-infix-operator-how-to-specify-package/68775187?noredirect=1#comment121552334_68775187)):

```r
library(tidyverse)
`%+c%` <- crayon::`%+%`
"foo" %+% "bar" %>% print
#> NULL
"foo" %+c% "bar" %>% print
#> [1] "foobar"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>