# R: conflict between two definitions of (infix) operator: how to specify package?

Tags: r, function, infix-operator

In R, whenever two packages define the same function, it is easy to specify which package to use with `pkg::foo`. But how do you when the conflicted function is an *infix* operator, i.e. defined using `%%`?

As an example, both `ggplot2` and `crayon` define `%+%`. Is there a way I can use by default `ggplot2`'s `%+%`, but in a given line, using `crayon`'s `%+%`? Just doing `` crayon::`%+%` ``  is calling the right function (note the backticks), but does not work as infix operator anymore!? I can do `` crayon::`%+%`(a, b) ``, it works, but it is not the function as an operator!

Code:

```
> library(crayon)
> "foo" %+% "bar"
[1] "foobar"
> crayon::`%+%`("foo" ,"bar")
[1] "foobar"
> "foo" crayon::`%+%` "bar"
Error: unexpected symbol in ""foo" crayon"
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use namespaces with infix operators in R; the parser just won't recognize that syntax. You need to create an alias as suggested in the answer below. Or create your own version of the operator that does dispatching based on the classes you expect to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding from @MrFlick's comment:

> Unfortunately you can't use namespaces with infix operators in R; the parser just won't recognize that syntax. You need to create an alias as suggested in the answer below. Or create your own version of the operator that does dispatching based on the classes you expect to see.

---

Just an idea but: how about redefining the infix function's binding. Suppose the one from `ggplot2` is the one you are going to use most often in your code:

```
library(ggplot2)
`%+c%` <- crayon::`%+%`
```

This way you are correctly namespacing the `ggplot2` library and you just use a different binding for the `crayon` one.

Comment: thanks @Daniel! I think this, together with @MrFlick point in the comment, is the right approach. Do you want to integrate his comment for your answer to mark the issue as solved?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to me since MrFlick's explanation of the underlying issue is very good. But I am not sure how to "integrate a comment to an answer". I don't want to just copy-paste it. Sounds like plagiarism to me. Maybe MrFlick can edit the answer so that SO keeps track of it?

Comment: plagiarism is only if you don't cite!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(conflicted)
conflict_prefer("%+%", "ggplot2")
# Code using ggplot2 definition
conflict_prefer("%+%", "crayon")
# "given line" using crayon definition
conflict_prefer("%+%", "ggplot2")
# Code using ggplot2 definition
```

Comment: thansk! But I don't see how this answers the task: "Is there a way I can use by default ggplot2's %+%, but in a given line, using crayon's %+%?"

Comment: At the start of your code, put the line “conflict_prefer("%+%", "ggplot2")”. From this point on the namespace will be “ggplot2” for "%+%". That is, you will be using ggplot2's %+%. When you get to the point where you want to use crayon's %+%, put the line “conflict_prefer("%+%", "crayon")”. The namespace will now be “crayon” for “%+%”. That is, you will be using crayon's %+%. Now put your given line, using crayon's %+%. To return to the ggplot2 %+%, put the line “conflict_prefer("%+%", "ggplot2")“. The namespace will now be “ggplot2” for "%+%". You will again be using ggplot2's %+%.

Comment: I use this for the same problem, but with a different function.